# MVC 5 client side validation stop working after adding checked option to radiobutton

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, client-side-validation

I have very weird case. I'm developing a web application in MVC 5 and I have a problem with simple form and client side validation. Please take a looke at this fragment of code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Announcements", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "addAnnouncementForm" }))
{

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LocationType, LocationTypeEnum.Krakow)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LocationType, LocationTypeEnum.Neighborhood)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StreetName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StreetName)

<input type="submit" value="Test" />
}
```

It works fine, but when I change the first radiobutton into this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LocationType, LocationTypeEnum.Krakow, new { @checked = "checked" })
```

(adding 'checked' option)
Then client side validation stop working, the form makes postback to server immadiately.

Does anybody know what can be the reason of such situation ? It's extremaly weird for me :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Since your radiobuttons names are same one of the radio buttton is clicked aplpication will post back unless you have some other validation set on your model

Comment: You must have changed something else as well because just adding `new { @checked = "checked" }` would not be the problem. (p.s. better to set the value of `LocationType` to `LocationTypeEnum.Krakow` in your controller before passing the view rater than setting the html attributes)

Comment: I did it in that way exactly. This is my controller action:  <br/>    public ActionResult AddAnnouncement()
    {
        var newAnnouncement = new AddAnnouncementViewModel
        {
            DictionaryItems = this._dictionaryService.GetDictionaryItems().ToList()
            //LocationType = LocationTypeEnum.Krakow.ToString()
        };
        return View(newAnnouncement);
    }  <br/>when I uncomment LocationType the client side validation stop working.